# Slickgrid Multiple Checkbox Columns - Both getting selected

Tags: slickgrid

I have a slickgrid with 2 Check box columns.

Both their Id's are different:

[image]

[image]

but still, when i select one checkbox [of one column], the other[column] checkbox gets selected as well.

What needs to be done?

Comment: I don't think the checkbox row selection plugin was ever written to support more than 1 column per grid, I'm pretty sure it's not. You can always contribute to the project to make it happen

Comment: Technically speaking it's meant to be a row selection (the entire row), so why would you add 2 checkbox anyway? Again I don't think the current code support more than 1 column checkbox

Comment: in addition to what @ghiscoding said, if you just want a checkbox to edit a boolean value, use the Checkbox editor